# Ruby console in website like www.rubymonk.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

Maybe someone made this or knows how to make this?

How can I make console in website like http://www.rubymonk.com or http://tryruby.org/. The website will expect the user to write something to console and that will give back output with an error or the correct answer.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! As you are new to SO, you might want to read the following help pages: ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Here are some thoughts.  It seems basic because all you have to do is send a line of user data to the server, use ruby to eval it, and then return the result. But then you have to think about things like multiple line blocks of code or literals. And on top of that, you'll need to sanitize things so harmful code isn't evaled. In fact it would be better if you created a separate, virtual, safe environment for code to be evaled. All in all I think it would be pretty hard, looks like tryruby has a github repo, though: https://github.com/Sophrinix/TryRuby

Comment: Thank You for reply! I am talking with friend about: "In fact it would be better if you created a separate, virtual, safe environment for code to be evaled. All in all I think it would be pretty hard".

I know this console must be safe. Users can't get access to password to server and folders(files) also can't make new files and delete files or make infinite loops. Moreover what is "hard" with make this? I can block some dangerous functions in console for example: base64_decode.. what else?